# I cant update my ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

when i type the command sudo apt-get update it gives me results saying "Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." this is the exact response i'm getting pliz help me guys

Comment: Whats the output of 'sudo apt-get -f install'  ?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update | grep '^E:\|^W:'` and [edit] your question to add the output.

Comment: i didnt get a response on that. it just moved the cursor down with a blank space

Comment: In this case add the **full output** of  `sudo apt-get update` to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the following commands in the given order:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

If you still have errors, try running these commands with a better Internet connection. Sometimes, on a slow connection the packages fails to download properly.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely its a problem with a cached package! Try to run

```
apt-get update && apt get clean && apt-get check
```

(You need to run this as root)
This command updates your local package list, cleans the package cache, and checks for missing dependencies.

This command solves most problems with apt-get.

Comment: You list of commands might fix some apt problems, but definitely not this one.

Comment: i got the following response

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Answer (score -2):

1. Launch the Software Updater. Press the Superkey (Windows key) to launch the Dash and search for Update Manager.
2. Check for updates. Select the tab called "Updates". ...
3. Install the upgrade.

Photo like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this answer is badly formatted and pretty useless in this case.

Comment: i have checked for updates and it it saying the software running on this pc is up to date